# Receive LLDP (IEEE 802.1AB) Broadcast Messages with C# or C++

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, network-programming, ethernet

I would like to discover local ethernet devices in my C# application. These devices are sending LLDP (Link Layer Discovery Protocol) broadcast messages. LLDP is also known as IEEE 802.1 AB and comes on OSI Layer 2, means pure Ethernet.

I already discovered a way by using a NDIS driver like WinPCAP together with a .net wrapper like SharpPCAP. But: I don't want to sniff the network, only reading broadcast ethernet frames according to IEEE. Therefore this seems a little oversized... any other ideas?

Using C++ instead of C#? This brings the advantage to get direct access to the WinAPI instead of using the convinient but limited .net framework. I'm not so familiar with the WinAPI. Just checked out MS docs about this. I still don't see a way to get the LLDP content by WinAPI. Any more Ideas?

Comment: I do not think you can do it in c#.  Only c++.  First there is no difference between sniffing and reading, the code is the same except sniffer will break down all the fields to ascii.  You need to filter incoming IP for only Protocol LLDP.  Net Library does not allow access to all fields and types in the IP header.  LLDP is not one of the enumerated types so the only way of getting access is in c++ (not c#).

Comment: Thx. I added some thoughts of you in my post above.

Comment: What is wrong with using the NDIS driver?  You can just filter to return LLDP.  As I said there is no difference in Sniff and receive except the sniff parse entire results to text format while receive doesn't.

Comment: I got your point. Using a NDIS driver will most likely work. My App is intended to get used by ordinary people. Installing additial drivers and grand rights might scare them. Therefore, I try to limit those things to the minimum.

Comment: Try following code project : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18572/NDIS-MONITOR-NET-32-bit-v1-00